# Unable to mock the findAll() method from JPA Repository with JMockit

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, spring-data-jpa, jmockit

I have a service implementation with a method `getOne` that makes a call to `findById` at the repository layer. (My repository extends JpaRepository, so I did not have to implement `findAll` myself.) I have tried to mock `findAll` to return a new Facility with the code below.

```
new MockUp<FacilityRepository>() {

    @Mock
    public Facility findById(int id) {
        return new Facility(1, new Date(), "Active");
    }
};
```

My issue is that when I invoke `getOne` from the service implementation, I expected the mock `findAll` to be called and the mock Facility to be returned. But it doesn't and leaves me stumped. Why isn't the mock method being called?

Very new to JMockit, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot to find your repositories? It won't find this one, because it's a MockUp, not a JpaRepository.
Even if you got this to work, mocking a repository doesn't sound like a good idea: you'd only do that if you wanted to test that the code calling it is doing the right thing (since mocking is about checking behaviour rather than providing test data). You could try stubbing instead (just remove the JMockit parts) or using a proper fake with known test data (e.g. H2, SqlLite, Derby, etc.).

Comment: I haven't worked with JMockit so I can't provide a ready answer. However, I frequently use Mockito, with which it is easy to mock certain objects and inject them into others. See [this sample](https://github.com/manish-in-java/stackoverflow-questions/blob/master/45361609/src/test/java/org/example/service/FacilityServiceTest.java)  for how repositories can be mocked with Mockito. You can then try to come up with something similar for JMockit.

Comment: Thank you both. @manish I took your advice and ended up stubbing instead of using a mock